# Should a class/module in lib be required?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just wrote a small module in my Rail 3.0.0 application lib folder:

```
module AdminFilters

  def verify_is_admin
    if current_user.nil? || current_user.role != User::Role::ADMIN
      redirect_to :root, :alert => "You don't have enough permissions"
    end
  end

end
```

And in order to make it available for all my controllers :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   protect_from_forgery

   require "admin_filters"
   include AdminFilters

end
```

If I remove the require line, rails complains like this :

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationController::AdminFilters
```

Is it the normal behavior ? I thought that any rb file in the lib folder was auto-loaded by rails ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it was auto-loaded in Rails 2.x.x, but Rails 3 doesn't load files from `lib/` anymore. You should consider placing your files into the `config/initializers` directory.